# Rewriting rule from one subdomain to another subdomain

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Please help me in rewriting Apache rule

I have a subdomain like **subdomain.domain1.com/a/b/c.jpg**

i want it to be like **subdomain.domain2.com/a/b/c.jpg**

Please how i can write

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[According to the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost) you don't have to use it at all if you have access to the server configuration. If they were on the same box AND you can edit the VirtualHosts file, then you can do this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.domain1.com

  Redirect / http://subdomain.domain2.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.domain2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Otherwise you'll need to do this with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html) in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain2.com/$1 [R,L,QSA]
```

Comment: i want to add here that both server different. actually the images are on some other server, i want user to see that images are on my server but when he open it then the call goes to second server, i just want to replace domain name like subdomain.domain1.com/a/b/c.jpg to subdomain.domain2.com/a/b/c.jpg

Comment: Then you're not trying to redirect at all. You'll likely need to use something like cURL or you'll need to do what Google does and make a copy of the images on your own server.